# String replace tab characters

Tags: java

I have a String with couple of tab characters. I want it all replace with '|'

```
String s = "\tcat\t\t\tball\t";
String b = s.replaceAll("\t+", "|");

System.out.println(b);
```

`|cat|ball|` gets printed out. Expected is `|cat|||ball|`

Comment: Why do you have the '+' in there.  That '+' says "one or more occurrences" so each match consists of all consecutive '\t' characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `s.replaceAll("\t+", "|")` to `s.replaceAll("\t", "|")` as follows:

```
String s = "\tcat\t\t\tball\t";
String b = s.replaceAll("\t", "|");
System.out.println(b);
```